# Flutter Riverpod : The member 'state' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart'

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have simple example about toggle widget,my expectation after click button i show circularProgressIndicator then after 3 second i showing Text. For my example i use [riverpod_hooks](https://riverpod.dev/) and [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks).

### LoadingProvider

```
class IsLoading extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  IsLoading() : super(false);
  void toggleLoading(bool value) => state = value;
}

final isLoadingProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => IsLoading());
```

### Main.dart

```
class TestingApp extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final IsLoading isLoading = useProvider(isLoadingProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: isLoading.state ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text('This Is Your Data'),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => showLoading(isLoading), child: Text('Toggle Loading')),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showLoading(IsLoading isLoading) async {
    isLoading.toggleLoading(true);
    print("Proses");
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    print("Done");
    isLoading.toggleLoading(false);
  }
}
```

But when i press the button , it's not show progressIndicator and still showing the text and i got this warning : 
`The member 'state' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart'.`

I missed something ?

> My source code following the documentation like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It says right there that it won’t trigger the method to rebuild when you call increment like that.

so instead of isLoading.toggleLoading(true)
call with a read method so it can rebuild the state like that
isLoading.read(context).toggleLoading(true)

Answer (score 1):

Provide two types for your `StateNotifierProvider`, the type of class you are returning and the state the class has.

```
class IsLoading extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  IsLoading() : super(false);
  void toggleLoading(bool value) => state = value;
}

final isLoadingProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<IsLoading, bool>((ref) => IsLoading());
```

in your `build` method (of a `ConsumerStateWidget`) use:

```
final isLoading = ref.watch(isLoadingProvider);
return Scaffold(body: Center(child:
isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text('This Is Your Data'),))
```